# Python Cron job on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I have a python program that I want to run every 10 seconds, just like cron job. I cannot use sleep in a loop because the time interval would become uncertain. The way I am doing it now is like this:

```
interval = 10.0
next = time.time() 

while True: 
    now = time.time() 
    if now < next: 
        time.sleep(next - now) 
        t = Thread(target=control_lights,)
        t.start()# start a thread
    next += interval
```

It generates a new thread that executes the contro_lights function. The problem is that as time goes, the number of python process grows and takes memory/CPU. Is there any good way to do this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Why don't you let `cron` do this?

Comment: @Blender: Probably because `cron` can't run jobs more often than once a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a program called [The Fat Controller](http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/) which is a scheduler similar to CRON but has many more options.   The interval can be measured from the end of the previous run (like a for loop) or regularly every x seconds, which I think is what you want.   Particularly useful in this case is that you can tell The Fat Controller what to do if one of the processes takes longer than x seconds:

- run a new instance anyway (increase parallel processes up to a specified maximum)
- wait for the previous one to finish
- kill the previous one and start a new one

There should be plenty of information in the documentation on how to get it set up.

Answer (score 1):

may be try use supervisord or god for this script? It is very simple to use and to control a number of you'r processes on UNIX-like operating system

Answer (score 0):

You can run a cron job every 10 seconds, just set the second param to '0/10'. It will run on 0, 10, 20 etc

```
#run every 10 seconds from mon-fri, between 8-17
CronTrigger(day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='8-17', second='0/10')
```